# WCF Windows authentication with netTcp binding. How to log SecurityNegotiationException on the server?

Tags: windows, wcf, authentication, logging, wcf-security

Usually on the WCF server side I would inherit BehaviorExtensionElement and add IServiceBehavior, which in turn would add IErrorHandler to all ChannelDispatchers to log all unhandled exceptions.

It works just fine for all the exceptions but this: SecurityNegotiationException which happens when client tries to connect with credentials which server doesn't know about (e.g. server is in one windows domain and client is in another windows domain, thus server can't authenticate client and client receives SecurityNegotiationException with error message "The server has rejected the client credentials").

The question is: how can I catch such exceptions (SecurityNegotiationException) on the server side?

Comment: Are you looking at implementing custom code during security negotiation?

Comment: I would better have it as some handler which is invoked every time the auth. process occurs.